# Database table update in vaadin

Tags: java, mysql, database, sql-update, vaadin

I was working with the following code to update my database table with the following code. Database connection is established, no exceptions shown, but my database table is not getting updated.

```
private void setupSaveButton(){
saveButton.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {            

@Override
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

   try {                       
    String updateQuery = "UPDATE " + MySqlConnectionManager.getDatabaseTableName()
    + " SET  BUGID='" + bugIdTextField.getValue()                                   
     + "', USERID='" + userIdTextField.getValue()
    + "', SUBJECT='" + subjectTextField.getValue()                                
    + "', COMMENT='" + commentTextArea.getValue() 
    + "', STATUS='" + statusComboBox.getValue()
    + "', OWNER='" +ownerTextField.getValue()
    + "', PRIORITY='" + priorityComboBox.getValue()                                
    + "' WHERE DATE='"+dateTextField.getValue()+"'; ";


        Connection connection = MySqlConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection();
         if(connection!=null){
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Query " + updateQuery);
        stmt.executeUpdate(updateQuery);
        }              
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BugDetailDisplay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }

 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I guess you are using `DateField` for date.*

Default date format of MySql is `YYYY-MM-DD` while your `dateTextField.getValue()` will return `Date` Object and default `toString` representation of `Date` will be concatenated in your query.So,both formats are different and your query executes successfully but can not detect the row with date you get from `dateTextField`.You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to format result of `dateTextField.getValue()` to allow query to find matching row.

---

If you are using simple *`textField`* than make sure your date format must match with MySql date.